# align a p5 canvas to a css grid

Tags: canvas, css-grid, p5.js

im tring to align a p5 canvas to a css grid for a project and its not playing nice.
i want to align the canvas inside the grid to experiment with layout to my project
my html file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>This is a empty p5 file</h1>
                <h2>also using Nedb </h2>
            </div>

            <div class="views">
                <p>views can be used by ether</p>
                <a class="vue" href="https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/">vuejs</a>
                <a class="pug" href="https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html">Pugjs</a>
        
            </div>

            <div class="canvas">
                <p>below is a canvas</p>
                <script src="js/sketch.js"></script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

and my css file

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [L] 1fr [M] 1fr [R];
  grid-template-rows: [T] 1fr [M] 1fr [B];
}

.header {
  grid-column: L/R;

  justify-self: center;
}
header.h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.views, .canvas {
  grid-column: L;
  grid-row: M;
}
.views { 
  align-self: start; 
}
.canvas { 
  align-self: end; 
}

.p5Canvas {
  grid-column: M;
  grid-row: M;
}
```

its saying its not a grid element.
is there something I'm missing
i can get most anything i want to do what i want but except this canvas.

Answer (score 0):

p5 canvas isn't html element. To get html you have to write something like this in JavaScript:

> let canvas = createCanvas(500, 500);

> let htmlCanvas = canvas.canvas;

Now you can modify CSS directly from JavaScript.
If you want to modify it in CSS file, then you should open developer tools, probably ctrl+shift+j, and read class name from Elements tree.

Comment: i tried that no difference.  and thats how i got the .p5canvas

Answer (score 0):

ended up something like this
sketch.js:

```
function setup() {
  let mycanvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  mycanvas.parent('canvas');
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
}
```

relevent html:

```
<div class="canvas" id="canvas">
    <p>below is a canvas</p>
    <script src="js/sketch.js"></script>
</div>
```